# python lxml scrape price by xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml, lxml.html

Look I need the price of this cryptocurrency
https://dex.guru/token/0x68848e1d1ffd7b38d103106c74220c1ad3494afc-bsc
With this code:

```
import lxml
import requests
from lxml import html

html = requests.get('https://dex.guru/token/0x68848e1d1ffd7b38d103106c74220c1ad3494afc-bsc')
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)
new_releases = doc.xpath('//div[@class="0.00047061210058486165"]/text()')[0]
print(new_releases)
```

But I get this error
`IndexError: list index out of range`
I know it's raising the error because the list is empty, but why is the list empty?
Please help, I am starting with scraping.

Comment: The page content is generated by JavaScript. lxml is not a web browser, so you probably need something like Selenium (https://selenium.dev).

Comment: Yes @mzjn is right, this website is cloudflare protected too.

Comment: @ce.teuf how do you find out which website is Cloudflare protected?
What about that website?https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x68848e1d1ffd7b38d103106c74220c1ad3494afc
I just need the price of the coin.

Comment: @AntonEitenbichler when you go to F12-> Network-> XHR you can see a POST request which returns the price you are looking for.  But in header response, you can see : "server : cloudflare". I make some tries and its bring back a 403 page (with a redirection on cloudflare page : "this is a cloudflare protected service ... your IP : ... " or something like this).

Comment: @AntonEitenbichler I believe you need to find a site which allow api calls. FYI, DexGuru says : https://docs.dex.guru/api

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution (imperfect one for the moment) :

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=15, interpreter='nodejs')
url = "https://api.dex.guru/v2/tokens/price"
json = {"ids":
            ["0x68848e1d1ffd7b38d103106c74220c1ad3494afc-bsc",
            "0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c-bsc"]}
            
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"}

resp = scraper.post(url, headers=headers, json=json)

# when it works
print(resp.json())
```

You need to install 'cloudscraper' package with one js interpreter (here i used nodejs). This code sometimes failed to return data, sometimes return data. I will investigate to find out why such instability is observed.

when it works, it returns:

```
{'total': 2,
 'data': [{'address': '0x68848e1d1ffd7b38d103106c74220c1ad3494afc',
   'token_price_usd': 0.0003694899811954059,
   'token_price_eth': 5.0304271359669745e-06},
  {'address': '0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c',
   'token_price_usd': 481.9784105344807,
   'token_price_eth': 6.533152208208108}]}
```

It's possible to build a better code with setting a session and saving temporary cookies generated by cloudflare (read 'cloudflare' doc).

Note that when their official API is released, we will prefer to use it.

Maybe cloudflare ban u if you put that kind of code in a loop without sleep() control.